# How to switch from Apache to Apache2 in H-Sphere

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an HSphere cluster that is currently running the latest version of H-Sphere 3.6.  Going through the PCI certification, I got flagged for CVE-2012-0053, which is related to the version of apache currently running.  At the moment this server is running apache 1.3.42-6, though it also has apache 2.2.22-7 installed.  The 2.2.22 version does not have this PCI issue and I was wanting to try switching the server over to run with apache2 instead of apache 1.x, however I've been unable to locate any documentation on how to do this.

My question is: What is the cleanest way to try apache2 in H-Sphere on a server, while being able to back out if there are issues?

```
rpm -qa | grep apache
hsphere-apache2-h3.1-2.2.22-7
hsphere-apache-utils-h3.1-1-0
hsphere-apache-h3.1-1.3.42-6
hsphere-apache-shared-h3.1-1-35
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
Edit: /hsphere/shared/scripts/scripts.cfg and change apache_version=2
service httpd restart
```

Keep in mind there are separate php.ini files for apache and apache2:

```
/hsphere/local/config/httpd2/php5/php.ini
/hsphere/local/config/httpd2/php53/php.ini
and
/hsphere/local/config/httpd/php5/php.ini
/hsphere/local/config/httpd/php53/php.ini
```

so you will probably need to review the httpd2 settings to make sure everything still works.